# How to use DotLiquid to replace the column text?

Tags: liquid, dotliquid

I have code written in liquid. The problem is, I want to rename some columns but I am stuck. I have tried but cannot find a way.

I have tried `for-loop` for instance replace text with variable. Also tried the text changing. The column name `Sub-Total` to be replaced with `Amount excluding tax`. The column name `total` to be replaced with `Amount including Tax`.

```
{% for total in table.totals %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="{{ table.columns | size | minus:1 }}" style="padding: 5px 10px; text-align: right{% if total.emphasis == true %}; font-weight: bold{% endif %}">
            {{ total.label }}
        </td>
        <td style="border-left-width: 1px; white-space: nowrap; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; padding: 5px 10px; text-align: right{% if total.emphasis == true %}; font-weight: bold{% endif %}">
            {{ total.text }}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

[image: Need this]